# Docker image 1 first layer

Tags: image, docker, containers, layer

I analyzed the docker image of mongodb with portainer.
but the root of the layers is a fiel.

What is this file in the first layer? :
1.

*ADD file:93883f863ccd9e401e4f945206887f251075a63d25a8129c9bd73e707397f109 in /*

and how can I analyse the origin and the content of it.

thanks

Comment: It's probably a tar file of a base Linux distribution; an Alpine, Debian, or Ubuntu image.  You'd have to look back at the original image's Dockerfile and the chain of images above that.  This usually doesn't matter much for practical programming purposes.

Comment: hi, yes I understand but I want to be confident what is in my image and where it is come frome. where can i look up the hash file ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no general location to lookup those hashes that I know of. It's a hash of the contents of the build context file or directory that is being added.

You can go upstream and look at how the base image is created. For example, looking at the [docker library](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images) reference for the current alpine image takes me to [the alpine project](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/tree/v3.14/x86_64) with a Dockerfile and tgz file. The digest is performed on that tgz file by the builder so the builder to identify if a cached version of this image can be reused, so I wouldn't consider it useful for reversing it to get the contents.

Instead, if you want to know what is inside the file and don't have access to the upstream image source like we have for Alpine and other official images, you can pull the layers from the registry and example the contents. There are tools like [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) for examining images, but I haven't had time to research the code to know if it's safe to trust this with access to the docker socket. You can pull the layers directly from the registry. For that, I tend to use [regclient/regctl](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) myself since I've been writing it, but there's also go-containerregistry's crane, and RedHat's skopeo that can probably do the same. Or you can use `docker save` to convert the image to a set of tar files to inspect each one. From regctl, inspecting alpine looks like:

```
$ regctl image manifest alpine:latest
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 1471,
    "digest": "sha256:14119a10abf4669e8cdbdff324a9f9605d99697215a0d21c360fe8dfa8471bab"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 2814446,
      "digest": "sha256:a0d0a0d46f8b52473982a3c466318f479767577551a53ffc9074c9fa7035982e"
    }
  ]
}

$ regctl blob get alpine:latest sha256:a0d0a0d46f8b52473982a3c466318f479767577551a53ffc9074c9fa7035982e | tar -tvzf -
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/arch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/ash -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/base64 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/bbconfig -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0          829000 2021-06-29 12:21 bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/cat -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/chgrp -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2021-08-27 07:05 bin/chmod -> /bin/busybox
...
```

Comment: thanks fore you good answer. so we can say : 1. if it is not official image than somthing fishy can be inside. and i have to unpack and scan it by my own. 2. if it is official image like mongo:xxxx I trust them. but somtimes in official image diffrent accounts upload images. specialy old images Iam  concern of if I can not prove the base image.

Comment: @DenisSteif I would start at your docker build process, the Dockerfile and from line, and see if you trust that base image. Dissecting the image is more forensics after the fact, and not a very user friendly way to manage your trust.